# PsychoPy - Contrast sensitivity measurement - Pokorny&Smith pedestal task

Tags: psychopy, contrast

I am very new to stackoverflow and programming, but I could not find any previous topic on the subject. In the context of my PhD in Psychology I would like to run a **psychophysical task to measure contrast sensitivity** in clinical patients (alcohol-dependent ones actually). Based on the literature, I have chose to use a well-known and often used task in the field: namely the **3-step steady and pulsed pedestal task** initially created by Joël Pokorny and Vivianne Smith. I have searched for existing scripts of this task on the internet a few months ago and recall having found useful pieces of script for it at that time. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find them anymore. I was therefore wondering whether anyone on Stack overflow would have any relevant material to share? Did anyone ever used this task or something equivalent/close?

Broadly speaking, it this task, participants are presented with 4 squares of equal luminance against a background that has a specific luminance too. At some point, the luminance of one of those 4 squares is either increased or decreased and participants have to specify which square changed during the trial. Depending on the habituation time to the background and the degree of change of luminance, participants rather rely on their parvocellular or magnocellular visual pathway, which allows, at the end of the task, to plot a psychophysical curve of parvocellular and magnocellular sensitivity and gain in contrast.
The idea in my case is to compare this curves in healthy participants versus alcohol-dependent patients.

Here are the references of the task:

Pokorny, J., & Smith, V. C. (1997). Psychophysical signatures associated with magnocellular and parvocellular pathway contrast gain. J. Opt. Soc. Am. A, 14(9), 2477–2486. https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.14.002477

Pokorny, J. (2011). Review: Steady and pulsed pedestals, the how and why of post-receptoral pathway separation. Journal of Vision, 11(5), 7. https://doi.org/10.1167/11.5.7

Any help would be highly appreciated as it would allow me not to start from scratch, especially since this would be my first attempt to program a task.
I am planning to do this using PsychoPy.

Many many thanks in advance.

Coralie

Comment: Looks like you have a fascinating research topic! Unfortunately you're unlikely to find someone who's done that specific thing on this site. What can you share about the scripts you found before? Were they in someone else's dissertation? Maybe your advisor knows who they were. If you know what language they were written in that can help with your searches. More information about the scripts themselves would help us answer your question.

Comment: Hi @CoralieCreupelandt, this is not so much a general programming question to StackOverflow as it is a domain-specific science question. I'd suggest that you'll get more useful responses on the PsychoPy user forum at  https://discourse.psychopy.org where the users understand the software you want to use but also are more likely to be familiar with (at least related) phenomena and techniques.